# Name output shows "null" Java

Tags: java

I am making a game-ish type of thing with three classes, combined. **NOT HOMEWORK; hobby.**

Codes for three classes:

**Runner:**

```
  public class CounterGameRunner
  {
  // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
   public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    CounterGameCounter game = new CounterGameCounter();

    System.out.println("You want to play a game I see. What is your name?");

    String name = input.next();

    game.NameIn(name);


    CounterGAME game1 = new CounterGAME();

    game1.actual();

}
}
```

**Actual Game:**

```
public class CounterGAME
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int number;
        int count=1;
        boolean loop = true;
    public  CounterGAME(){


    }

    public void actual(){

        CounterGameCounter game2 = new CounterGameCounter();


        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 101, see how many times you get it!");

         number=input.nextInt();
         int r = (int)(Math.random() * (100) + 1);
        while(loop==true){


    if(number < r){
        System.out.println("Too small, try again");
        number = input.nextInt();
        count++;
        game2.Counter(count);

      } else if(number == r){
        System.out.println("Wow, you won! Who'd have thought?");
          count++;
           game2.Counter(count);
          break;

     System.out.println(game2.done());

      } else if(number > r){
         System.out.println("Too large, try again");
          number = input.nextInt();

          count++;

         game2.Counter(count);
     }


       }





      }



 }
```

**Counter Class:**

```
 public class CounterGameCounter
  {
       // instance variables - replace the example below with your own



 private String Name; 

String done1;
int correct;

public CounterGameCounter(){



}



public String NameIn (String nm){
   Name = nm;
    return Name;
}

public String NameOut(){

    return Name;

}


public void Counter(int count){

   correct = count;

}

public int getCount(){



    return correct;

}


public String done(){
  done1 = "Name:    "           + NameOut() + "\n" + 
          "Times Answered:    " + getCount();




    return done1;
  }



}
```

**Problem:**

The counter works properly and everything else displays and functions properly in the end. However, any name I input in the beginning always shows "null" while running the program. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable names are really confusing, and there are a lot of bad practices in your code, but `null` in name is because you create a new `Counter` in `CounterGAME`:

```
public void actual(){    
    // here
    CounterGameCounter game2 = new CounterGameCounter();  
    // more code
}
```

Change actual to receive a `CounterGameCounter`:

```
public void actual(CounterGameCounter game2){
    // more code
}
```

And call it like:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
    CounterGameCounter game = new CounterGameCounter();
    System.out.println("You want to play a game I see. What is your name?");
    String name = input.next();
    game.NameIn(name);
    CounterGAME game1 = new CounterGAME();    
    game1.actual(game);
    // more stuff
}
```

---

**FREE TIPS:**

- use `String getName()` and `void setName(String)`
- start variable, object and attribute names with `lowercase`

  ```
  String name;
  Object object;
  ```
- Variable names must be representative and descriptive

  ```
  CounterGameCounter counterGameCounter = new CounterGameCounter();
  ```

  This is also applicable to `Object` names:

  ```
  GameCounter gameCounter = new CounterGameCounter();
  ```

Comment: What does the game1.actual(game) represent?

Comment: @Aakarsh is the call to the modified `actual` method as I explained.... Finally you solve it? let me know if any problem with the name.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
String name = input.nextLine();
```

instead of:

```
String name = input.next();
```